# Collect objects from the "side" of 3 dimensional array

Tags: java

I'm making a project for a course at university. It's some kind of rpg which consists out of 3 dimensional dungeons. every dungeon is a cube holding squares. Now what I need to do is "collect" all squares from the sides of the cube.

I could easily do this by making 6 for loops but I don't think thats a very elegant way of doing this.
Does anyone know a better way of solving this problem then by using a ton of for loops?

Comment: A little more info on how the stuff is arranged might help here.  I'm having trouble picturing the layout/structure -- at least, i'm having trouble picturing a layout that's not trivial to do this for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in 3 dimensions, the most obvious way to store that information is in a 3 dimensional structure like a 3-dimensional array. That would allow you easily select all items at the 6 sides of the cube by getting all blocks where either a dimension is 0 or *maximum*. Where maximum is the size of the array.

However, this is all highly speculative without a bit of code. Maybe if you post what you have now it will help get you some more concrete answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over two dimensions and do all 6 faces at once.

```
for (u...) {
    for (v...) {
        add(cube[0][u][v];
        add(cube[M][u][v];
        add(cube[u][0][v];
        add(cube[u][M][v];
        add(cube[u][v][0];
        add(cube[u][v][M];
    }
}
```